# How to join three tables and set blank fields to null?

Tags: sql

[image]

I used `full join` and `left join` to join the `Person`, `Tasks` and `Task` tables. The result shown on the screen resulted in a number of lines greater than six. Unset fields have the value `NULL` and that's good.

The expected output can be obtained using such `joins`, however it is necessary to use clauses that allow the common fields to be joined. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CROSS JOIN` produces all the combinations you want. Then a simple outer join can retrieve the related rows (should they exist).

You don't mention the database you are using so a faily standard query will do. For example (in PostgreSQL):

```
select
  row_number() over(order by p.id, t.id) as id,
  p.name,
  case when x.st is not null then t.hr end,
  x.st
from person p
cross join tasks t
left join task x on x.personid_fk = p.id and x.taskid_fk = t.id
order by p.id, t.id;
```

Result:

```
 id  name  case   st    
 --- ----- ------ ----- 
 1   Anna  null   null  
 2   Anna  null   null  
 3   Luo   13:00  true  
 4   Luo   14:00  false 
 5   John  null   null  
 6   John  null   null
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vkgS6VmcUYhTB9iNs9yq7C/0).

Comment: This `sql` is not working in `phpMyAdmin`. A message informs you that there is a syntax error, see: https://ibb.co/8srMgRv Information: https://ibb.co/YD1P4x5

Comment: Hi John, as you can see the query is for PostgreSQL, not MySQL. You didn't mention any specific database. Anyway, for MySQL you'll need to use at least version 8.x.

Comment: Understand. His comments were very helpful. Thanks.